# Console keeps printing hexadecimal instead of contents in the array

Tags: c++, arrays, output

I'm trying to create an array of size 100 filled with 0's. When I go to print out the area what prints is: 0x7fff5fbff54c. It seems to be printing out the address of the area and I am not sure why and how I should fix this so that it prints out what it is supposed to. Below is my code.

List.hpp

```
typedef int ElementType;
const int MAX = 100;
class List
{
   public:
      List();
      bool Empty();
      void InsertAtEnd(ElementType x);
      void Delete(ElementType x);
      void Display();
      int Smallest();
      int Largest();
      int Range();

   private:
      int N;
      ElementType listArray[MAX];

};
```

List.cpp

```
    #include "List.hpp"
    #include <iostream>
    using namespace std;

    List::List() {

        listArray[99] = {0};
    }

    void List::Display() {

        cout << listArray;

   }
```

main.cpp

```
    #include "List.hpp"
    #include <iostream>
    using namespace std;

    int main() {

       List list;
       list.Display();
       return 0;
    }
```

Comment: It seems as though you come from python programming where `print(listArray)` would print the entire array however in c++ you cannot do this and need to write a loop that visits each element

Comment: You are printing a pointer value, so that's what's expected.

Comment: I changed it so that it uses a for loop and now it prints 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1606416136 32767 1606422582 @πάνταῥεῖ

Comment: @Krae So you're printing uninitialized values now? Provide a [MCVE] please.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ what do you mean? i've provided the code and the output

Comment: @Krae `listArray[99] = {0};` Just initializes the value at index `99` to `0` in that context you show. You probably intended something different?

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ I am trying to initialize all the values in the array to 0. I am unsure of how to do this.

Answer (score 2):

That is because listArray is a pointer, you are printing the address of the pointer.. If you want to print the content you need to write a loop that will iterate through each element and print the values.

something like:

```
for (int i=0; i< MAX; ++i)
{
   cout << listArray[i] << ", ";
}

cout << endl;
```

@πάνταῥεῖ is correct. Try this instead:

```
 class List
 {
    public:
       List();
       bool Empty();
       void InsertAtEnd(ElementType x);
       void Delete(ElementType x);
       void Display();
       int Smallest();
       int Largest();
       int Range();

    private:
       int N;
       ElementType listArray[MAX] = {0};

 };
```

And remove the initialization from your constructor

Comment: Now it prints 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1606416136 32767 1606422582 @Rob

Answer (score 1):

Wouldn't you want a loop:

see this previous question:

[loop through an array in c++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16660237/loop-through-an-array-in-c)

Answer (score 0):

The code you have

```
List::List() {
    listArray[99] = {0};
}
```

Just initializes the value of your `listArray` at index `99`.

To initialize your array with all values as `0` you need to use the constructors initializer list:

```
List::List() : listArray {0} {
}
```